# How to get statistics for events without event category?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

Due to a typo, events were sent to the Google Analytics without event category. I see these events with category *(not set)* in real time statistics, but they are not in *Behavior > Events*. And i cannot compile a report on these events.

Maybe there is some way to get statistics on these events? Maybe through the Google API?

Comment: Once the data is written to google anlaytics its set in stone.  If the data doesnt exist then not even the api can find that data.

Comment: @DaImTo Maybe the problem is that i'm not very good at looking for them. Maybe through the API i will see what i do not see through the GI. I'm not sure there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

The category, together with the action, is a mandatory parameter for the event. If it is *undefined* you can only hope that it is recognized as undefined as string (sometimes it happens that they are acquired like this, but you would see it in the report), otherwise the hit will be discarded and the data will not exist.